# Odd error from an RSpec/Capybara Test - Calling create from a controller doesn't finish before the test check.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Here the main part of the test:

```
it "should add an energy level correctly", :js => true do
  visit energy_tracking_path 
  find(".energy-4").click
  click_button "Submit"

  @user.energy_levels.should_not be_empty
  @user.energy_levels.last.level.should be_equal(4)  
  @user.energy_levels.last.date.should be_present

end
```

Right now the first test returns an error:

```
Failure/Error: @user.energy_levels.should_not be_empty
   expected empty? to return false, got true
```

However, if I put a `binding.pry` line right in between `click_button "Submit"` and the first test, the entire thing passes.

"Submit" sends the selected energy level to its controller and creates it.

It looks like the `create` method isn't finishing before the the first test is run, but when `binding.pry` is put in, it gives the test time to finish the method. Has anyone else run into this problem/have a solution?

Comment: Is the submit fired off via Ajax? You will have to wait for it to finish then. The best way to do that is to wait for content to change. For example, a flash message popping up.

Comment: No, it's just a submit button for a form_for. =/

Comment: Adding a `sleep 1.seconds` line fixes it, but I really don't like that fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding a `page.should have_content("Success")` line right after the `click_button "Submit"`. I guess this ensures that the page loads first before checking the database.

Comment: Yes, the have_content matcher (and have_css and have_xpath) will wait until they pass, up until a limit, which you can change by adding `Capybara.default_wait_time = 5` to your env.rb, or just in certain steps. It's a setter and getter.